# Different output on recursive call using static variable

Tags: c++, c, recursion, static

```
int fun1(int x){
    static int n;
    n = 0;
    if(x > 0){
        n++;
        return fun1(x-1)+n;
    }
    return 0;
}
int fun(int x){
    static int n = 0;
    if(x > 0){
        n++;
        return fun(x-1)+n;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me the difference between fun and fun1 ?
Getting different output!!

Comment: Apart from the multitagging (is this C or C++) and the fact you don't tell us what the input and output is in both cases, and `main` is missing which would have been useful, this is a good question. Do take the time to amend it please.

Comment: Thanks will take a note about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `static int n = 0;` is one time initialization

Like the snippet below,

```
bool initialized = false;
static int n;

int fun1(int x){
  if(!initialized){
    n = 0;
    initialized = true;
  }
  if(x > 0){
    n++;
    return fun1(x-1)+n;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

2. `static int n; n =0` is reset to zero on every recursive call. Like below,

```
bool initialized = false;
static int n;
int fun(int x){
  if(!initialized){
    n = 0;
    initialized = true;
  }
  n = 0;
  if(x > 0){
    n++;
    return fun(x-1)+n;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In reality `n` is part of [.BSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) and initialized to zero at load time.

Comment: Technically speaking, the second case is not an initialization. It's an assignment.

Comment: @klutt : is it just a resetting? Please verify my updates

Comment: You can read about initializations here:https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9

Comment: Simplified: Initializations are done at compile time while assignments are done in run time

Comment: @klutt, that's perhaps *over*-simplified - initialization of static variables in function scope occurs *the first time the function is called*.

Comment: @TobySpeight Are you 100% sure? Because this does NOT compile: `void foo(int n) { static int x = n; }`

Comment: @TobySpeight : why not at a load time for primitive data type? If  it is `static` `object` it make sense to initialize when function is called(i.e through constructor call)?

Comment: @TruthSeeker, what constructor?  Those are free functions.

Comment: @TobySpeight : in case of  static object constructor has to be called only once. hence initialization done on function call. But  in-case of compile time `const` like `static int x = 10` isn't the initialization done at load time?

Comment: @klutt, I might be mixing up with C++, where the initializer doesn't need to be a compile-time constant.  Sorry!

Comment: @TobySpeight Common mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

In `fun1`, `n` is set to `0` every time the function is called.

In `fun`, `n` is initialised to `0` at program start but thereafter only updated by `n++`.